# Binding from codebehind (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have SqlDataSource assigned to a GridView, and a lot of the fields returned are only used in the code behind to determine whether a column is visible, etc. Currently I bind these vlaues to a hiddenfield, however this adds a lot of code to the source file which isn't ideal.

Can I get the values for the row from the codebehind, without having to assign them to a hiddenfield in the markup?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't - perhaps handle the one of the DataBinding or Creating events for the GridView, and pull the information you need from the SqlDataSource?  If I had more time, I'd try and put together a sample to verify it, but it seems like a plausible approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code behind, you can access the values through the `DataItem` object

Example

```
DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

// Retrieve the state value for the current row. 

String state = rowView["state"].ToString();
```

Or you could convert the value to an object and play around with it.

Take a look here for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx